# openGL, GLFW, 1281 error on glShaderSource, the very next glShaderSource works fine somehow

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glfw

I've been trying to get shaders to work. They don't.

```
std::cout << "a " << glGetError() <<std::endl; //making sure things work
GLuint vertexShader = 0;
GLuint fragmentShader = 1;
glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
std::cout <<"b " << glGetError() <<std::endl;
glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
std::cout <<"c " << glGetError() <<std::endl;
glShaderSource(vertexShader, GLsizei(1), (const char**)&VertexShaderSource, NULL);//ERROR
std::cout <<"d " << glGetError() <<std::endl;
glShaderSource(fragmentShader, GLsizei(1), (const char**)&FragmentShaderSource, NULL);//is somehow fine
std::cout <<"e " << glGetError() <<std::endl;
glCompileShader(vertexShader);
std::cout <<"f " << glGetError() <<std::endl;
glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
std::cout <<"g " << glGetError() <<std::endl;'
```

Now, the output is:

```
a 0
b 0
c 0
d 1281
e 0
f 1281
g 0
```

This means that the first `glShaderSource` call is not working, but, for some reason the next `glShaderSource` works, while doing what I think is the exactly same thing.
What is going on in here???

Shaders are:

```
const std::string VertexShaderSource ="#version 330 core"
                                  ""
                                  "layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;"
                                  ""
                                  "void main()"
                                  "{"
                                  "    gl_Position = vec4(position.x, position.y, position.z, 1.0);"
                                  "}";

const std::string FragmentShaderSource ="#version 330 core"
                                    ""
                                    "out vec4 color;"
                                    ""
                                    "void main()"
                                    "{"
                                    "    color = vec4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);"
                                    "}";
```

And if passing string this way `((const char**)&VertexShaderSource)` is wrong, then why the second call works just fine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set `vertexShader` and `fragmentShader` to the result of `glCreateShader` instead of hardcoding it to `0` and `1`.

```
GLuint vertexShader;
GLuint fragmentShader;
vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
std::cout <<"b " << glGetError() <<std::endl;
fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
std::cout <<"c " << glGetError() <<std::endl;
```

The function [`glCreateShader`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glCreateShader.xhtml) returns `0` if it the call was not successful.

In your code you set `vertexShader` hardcoded to `0`, and opengl reports an error for `glShaderSource(vertexShader, ...` because you pass `0` as id to `glShaderSource`.

The `1281` is an `GL_INVALID_VALUE` error and is reported `if shader is not a value generated by OpenGL.`  [glShaderSource: Errors](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glShaderSource.xhtml#errors)

Beside that you `(const char**)&VertexShaderSource` is wrong to get the memory address where a `std::string` stores the data you have to use `.c_str()`:
[How to pass an std::string to glShaderSource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047527/how-to-pass-an-stdstring-to-glshadersource)

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the string wrongly, the correct way is `VertexShaderSource.c_str()`.